# setting styles images for use in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, themes

I am trying to make theme change option for my app .
I read here some similar problems like mine but non of the solution were working.

To my `styles.xml` I added :

```
<style name="themeBackground">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/background2</item>
    </style>
```

on the xml i added to the layot:

```
android:background="@style/themeBackground"
```

the error i get :

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060000 a=-1 r=0x7f060000}
```

I tried removing - `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` from manifest as suggested here in some other postand it didnt work. Any ideas ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file attrs.xml in the res/values/ dir and add code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<attr name="themeBackground" format="reference" />
</resources>
```